# How to know power consumption at the moment?

Tags: battery, samsung-galaxy-s7, resource-monitoring

From time to time my Samsung Galaxy S7 is starting to consume a lot of power, turns hot and eats 10% of charge in minutes.

If I have less than 10% charge, it kills itself even if on external power.

How to trace which application does this (and eliminate it)?

I tried GSam battery monitor, but it can display per application data only in average from last full charge time. I.e. it can't trace proccess which worked only minutes.

Are there any applications, which can trace simultaneously per time and per application?

Comment: Please add to your question of the device is rooted or not. If not AFAIK, no way of knowing

Comment: @beeshyams answer how to do this on rooted

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dp.sysmonitor.app